# Chrome notebook won’t boot

Tags: boot, google-chrome, uefi, images

It also says press any key to continue booting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a drive problem. It appears to have gone bad.Possible PCI and Sata errors and the computer just loops back when you press a key. You can try formatting and reinstalling the OS.

More than likely, you will need to replace the drive.

You can do this yourself if you have the knowledge and skill and the recovery USB.

Otherwise take it to a local computer shop and have them replace the drive and recover the OS.

Chromebooks are inexpensive, so check the estimate for repairing against the cost of a new machine.

Comment: It's kinda weird to jump to the conclusion that the drive has gone bad based on just a screenshot of EFI shell being booted to. Nothing on the screenshot is an error.

Comment: Edited tp reflect both more likely and less likely possibilities. Thank you.